# How to show Datatable buttons with language file included?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, internationalization, datatables

this should be basic datatable setup with buttons, i'm using it with bootstrap so as [suggested](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) i did:

```
var tab= $('#table').DataTable({
        buttons: true
    });

tab.buttons().container().appendTo( '#table_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
```

that's fine, it shows all buttons. Problem is that i need localisation for table, and when i use i.e.:

```
var tab= $('#table').DataTable({
    buttons: true,
    language: {
        url: "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/English.json"          
    },
});

tab.buttons().container().appendTo( '#table_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
```

buttons are not showing. I  looked at language file, there's no values for button keys, so i tried to add:

```
var tab= $('#table').DataTable({
    buttons: true,
    language: {
        url: "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/English.json",         
        buttons: {
            print: "Do Print",
            copy: "Copy to clipboard",
            pdf: "Make PDF",
            excel: "Make xlsx",
            csv: "Prepare csv"
        }
    },
});

tab.buttons().container().appendTo( '#table_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
```

but buttons are still not showing. Can you help me with this? 
(same is if i use any other language file.)

Answer (score 5):

> **SOLUTION #1**

Use the following value for [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option for displaying buttons inside the table container:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   dom: 
      "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
   language: {
      url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/English.json"          
   },
   buttons: [
      'copy', 'pdf', 'excel', 'csv'
   ]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j7xbrc5/3/) for code and demonstration.

> **SOLUTION #2**

You can also use direct insertion method as shown in [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) because default `dom` option used for Bootstrap styling is quite complex.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   language: {
      url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/i18n/English.json"          
   },
   initComplete: function(){
      var api = this.api();

      new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(api, {
         buttons: [
            'copy', 'pdf', 'excel', 'csv'
         ]
      });

      api.buttons().container().appendTo( '#buttons' );  
   }
});
```

Note that code above differs from the example referenced above because there is an [issue](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/646) with DataTables 1.10.9 preventing direct insertion of buttons if there is no `B` character in `dom` option or `dom` option is not specified.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j7xbrc5/2/) for code and demonstration

Comment: That's working, but now i cannot place buttons in container outside generated table... i didn't mention it at first, but it's needed.

Comment: @Yuray, I have added alternative solution for container outside the table.